# Check for Windows Form Completion

Tags: .net, winforms

I am trying to check whether all of the required info in a windows user form is complete before executing code at the end.

Are there any recomended ways of checking whether windows forms have been completed?

It seems that if I list each control and then check it that my code looks bloated as it goes on for some 40 controls.

e.g.

```
if(!check_1(varX_TextBox))
    return false;

if(!check_2(varY_ComboBox))
    return false;

...

if(!check_40(varAA_numericUpDown))
    return false;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I am trying to check whether all of the required info in a windows user form is complete". What info are you talking about? Are you talking about the loading of all controls in the form? Please explain!

Comment: Most forms are static so will be loaded by default.  I need to know if they contain text for TextBox or ComboBox (e.g. TexBox.Text != ""), have been checked if it is a TickBox etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many different ways of achieving this and it will eventually come down to your own personal preference as to which you use. That said, two good places to start with Windows Forms are the validation events that are part of the Windows Forms framework (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229603.aspx)) and the Enterprise Library [Validation Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648831.aspx).

The validaiton events `Validating` and `Validated` give you hooks to cleanly plug in your control validation, and most Windows Forms controls integrate with this framework cleanly. You can trigger this validation at a variety of times (such as form closing or when a control loses focus).

The Validation Application Block is very useful if you are using a Domain Model in your design. It allows you to decorate properties of classes with validation requirements and then provides classes that assist in the validation of these classes and the reporting of any errors.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested other solution you can go with them **or you can make your custom function as your requirements.**

Let me give you example. 

Suppose a form contains more than 15 textbox among them 10 are required. So set a message in **textbox's tag property** like **"xyz field is required"**.
*Now on submit form you can call something like below*

```
    foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
    {
        //All text boxes validate in one if statement
        if (c is TextBox && c.Tag.ToString() != string.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(c.Tag.ToString());
        }
    }
```

This is just example you can cover all the other type controls like combobox, checkbox etc..
Now that on you how you use validation. But you can do something like this also,

Answer (score 0):

You can use win-form validation controls, or implement some another validation mechanism, for example implement IDataErrorInfo in your view models (presenters).

Answer (score 0):

1. One way to do this is to create a validation class that holds all the properties you need to check. Change the properties of that class when a user changes textbox or checkbox etc. and then look for changes within the class. You need two states i.e. Valid State and Changed State and always compare the Changed state to the valid state. If both states are same then that means all the validation and checks on the form is as you desire.

Answer (score 0):

There is no other 'magic' way around what you are trying to do.  Every field, if has its requirements, will have its code snippet that does the validation for that field.

What you'll be able to choose from are the options on how to 'add' that validation snipped to the field:

- `OnValidate` event of each control
- timer that will check all of the controls on the form, each with its own snippet
- `OnChange` event of each control
- `OnOK` event for the 'accept' button on the form, that will go over each control and validate it

My favorite is none of the above, since I am very much binding-oriented, so I have a class for my data, bind that class to the form controls, and on 'accept' button I let my class do the DATA validation.